# VBA: How to display a checkbox only when a cell condition is met

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently making a calculator for calculating government aid for school. I'm trying to make it as user friendly and visually attractive as possible. That's why I'm trying to use VBA so the user doesn't have to make entries into the sheet directly.

I have a simple sheet where a user can input his data. On the left is a table for Person A, on the right Person B.

I also have a drop down list under Person A which checks whether he/she is single or married. When Person A is single, I want Person B to disappear completely from the sheet. No Problem at all for most of the entries. But I have Active-X elements under Person B as well (drop down lists, checkboxes) and it's not so easy to hide those because you need to be using VBA.

Is it possible to only show those elements when Person A is married?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if the drop-down is data-validation use the `Worksheet_Change` event. If the drop-down is an Active-X or Form Control listbox, then use the objects methods (maybe OnChange) to evaluate and then show the boxes for PersonB. You can also use the `Workbook_Open` method to hide the PersonB boxes when the workbook is open.

Comment: I'm using Active-X checkboxes. Sorry I am a beginner at programming. can I simply copy paste the method into the code of the Checkbox 2? How is it supposed to check the Content of the linked cell of Checkbox 1?

Comment: Insert the code in the `CheckBox_Change` event. Check the cell with `Range("A1").Value2`. I would also suggest reading a VBA tutorial and then if you get stuck writing your code come back with **specific** questions about the code you have.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the names of the controls you can simply do the following in the checkbox_click event. 
Say there's 2 checkboxes and CheckBox2 only should be visible when checkbox 1 is clicked:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    CheckBox2.Visible = False
Else
    CheckBox2.Visible = True
End If
End Sub
```

Or when based on a cell value when the worksheet changes:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Range("SingleOrMarried").value = "Single" Then 'Assuming a named range for the Single or not cell.
    CheckBox1.Visible = False
Else
    CheckBox1.Visible = True
End If
End Sub
```

The above assumes ActiveX-controls as you are using them. Code should be placed in the Worksheet-module of the worksheet that holds the controls. From another module you can use: `Worksheets("PersonsOrWhatever").CheckBox1.Visible = false`